# Find the longest word/string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just started learning JavaScript. I am trying to write a JavaScript to find and print the longest word in an Array. I came up with the code below:

```
var longWords = ["Penelope", "Johny", "Aubumayang", "Czechoslovakia", "Slovenia"]
var longest = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < longWords.length; i++) {
if (longest < longWords[i].length) {
    longest = longWords[i];
  }
}

console.log(longest)
```

The problem is it always end up printing the  first element in the array. which means `longest = longWords[0]`. Now when I change the line `longest = longWords[i]` to `longest = longWords[i].length` I get the count of the longest character. Please tell me why it didn't work and how I can do this using the `for` loop.

Comment: Do you need to handle the use case where two words are of equal length, and are both the longest?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (longest < longWords[i].length) {
```

Should probably be

```
if (longest.length < longWords[i].length) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You can custom sort based on string length, and grab the first item:

```javascript
longWords.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return b.length - a.length; 
});
```

This turns your array into the following:

```javascript
["Czechoslovakia", "Aubumayang", "Penelope", "Slovenia", "Johny"]
```

At that point, you can grab the first item. Note however that there may be other strings immediately following the first that are of the same length.

As for your above code, `longest` is declared as a number, but later set to a string. The number we're interested in comes from the length of the string. Our condition should be:

```javascript
// No sense in looking this up twice
current = longWord[i];

if ( longest.length < current.length ) {
    longest = current;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than finding the longest word, I'd suggest sorting the array by descending length of its elements, using `Array.prototype.sort()`:

```
var longWords = ["Penelope", "Johny", "Aubumayang", "Czechoslovakia", "Slovenia"],
    sorted = longWords.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.length < b.length;
});

console.log(sorted);
// ["Czechoslovakia", "Aubumayang", "Penelope", "Slovenia", "Johny"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WN33j/).

References:

- [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 1):

```
var longest = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < longWords.length; i++) {
    if ( longWords[i].length > longest.length ) {
        longest = longWords[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be easy to print the longest word if you `sort` the array and print the first element `arr.[0]`

---

```
var longWords = ["Penelope", "Johny", "Aubumayang", "Czechoslovakia", "Slovenia"];
var sorted = longWords.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length );

console.log(sorted[0]);
// "Czechoslovakia"
```

---

There's another nice way to get the longest element, and that is with the `reduce` method:

```js
var longWords = ["Penelope", "Johny", "Aubumayang", "Czechoslovakia", "Slovenia"];

var longest = longWords.reduce(
  (a, b) => a.length >= b.length ? a : b
);

console.log(longest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let longest = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < longWords.length; i++) {
  let word = longWords[i];
  if (longest < word.length) {
    longest = word.length;
  }
}
console.log(longest);
```

Comment: Hey Sekh Soyeb Ali, welcome to Stack Overflow :) Your question was flagged as low quality on here because you haven't explained your answer. I can see it's some simple code but try and write a little explanation when you answer!