# Finding longest word in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am currently working on a problem in coderbytes. I am supposed to create a function that takes in a string and returns the longest word in the string(no punctuation will be in the string and if there are two words the same size the function should return the first one). I was able to find a similar question [Find the longest word/string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987389/find-the-longest-word-string-in-an-array), but for some reason my code is not working.

```
var longestword = function(string){
    var longest = [];
    array = string.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].length > longest.length){
        longest = array[i];    
        }
    }
console.log(longest)
}    
longestword("This isnt workin for some reason")
```

The error I am getting is `TypeError: array[i] is undefined`

Comment: It's javascript, the variable need not be declared.   It's defined when it is assigned to on the third line.

Comment: The error you are speeking about is probably because you are using "<=" for the comparison in teh for() loop. Imagine your length is 9, your array will stop at 8 (because it begin at 0 not 1), use strict < not <= for the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is `i <= array.length`, but array indexes (for non-sparse arrays like this one) are `0` through `array.length - 1`. Just use `<`, not `<=`. You're getting `undefined` for `array[i]` when `i` is `array.length` because there's no element there.

---

Unrelated, but: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you never declare `array`. Add a `var` in front of `array = string.split(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access array[array.length].   Arrays are 0-based.  Change the <= to an <.

Comment: *"You can't access array[array.length]"* Well, you *can* (this is JavaScript!), but you'll get `undefined`. ;-)